# How to create input form which opens an alert box?

Tags: javascript, css, forms, validation

In HTML I have created a form to input text, using Javascript for validation, as you should be able to see below.

I want to make it so that when the submit button is clicked an alert box appears thanking the user for inputting data.

I can't seem to do this however without ruining the JS validation.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```js
    function validateForm() {
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
      if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please enter your name");
        return false;
      }
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
      if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address");
        return false;
      }
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["confirm"].value;
      if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please select an option");
        return false;
      }
    }
```

```css
 h1 {
   background-color: silver;
   color: black;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
 }
 hr {
   color: blue;
   width: thick;
 }
 body {
   font-size: 12pt;
   color: brown;
   font-family: Tahoma, Bodoni, sans-serif;
   line-height: 0.8em;
 }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Basic Form Markup</title>
  <meta charset="UFT-8" />
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Multi-Part Form</h1>
  <hr />
  <div>
    <form name="myForm" action+ "demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
      <h1>Name and E-mail</h1>
      <p>Name:
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" size="30" maxlength="250">
      </p>
      <p>E-mail:
        <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="50">
      </p>
      <p>Comments or Questions (optional)</p>
      <TEXTAREA NAME="Address" ROWS=3 COLS=80></TEXTAREA>
      <h1>Do you wish to receive regular emails giving information about GCEnterpise's ongoing projects?</h1>
      <!--Maybe change above to paragraph tag?-->
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="confirm" value="yes">Yes</p>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="confirm" value="no">No</p>

      <p style="line-height: 2em; margin: 2em;">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
      </p>
  </div>
  <hr/>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You want it to alert that if everything is alright, correct?

Comment: Yes. I want an alert to appear thanking them for entering their details and confirming that they have been submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't getting what is meant by without ruining js validation. you can simply add this small statement at end of your js validation script

> alert('Thanks for Data')

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didn't realise it would be that simple.